# Python How to get the tag value without the tag xml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

- I am using `findAll` method of `BeautifulSoup` and trying to fetch all the values of particular tag `DocumentIndex`.
- While using it, I am getting the output as

```
[<DocumentIndex>3646</DocumentIndex>, <DocumentIndex>3650</DocumentIndex>, <DocumentIndex>3649</DocumentIndex>]
```

- Code, gstr_xml is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZFHkklGpi2_yr5TZ7ua-LjEm1ze8ys7/view?usp=sharing)

```
lstr_soup = BeautifulSoup(gstr_xml, features="xml")
lstr_folder_index = lstr_soup.findAll('DocumentIndex')
print(lstr_folder_index)
```

- How can I get the output just as

```
[3646, 3650, 3649]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each value in the list is a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, which you can call `.text` on to retrieve just the text value.

```
print([x.text for x in lstr_folder_index])

# Output:
['3646', '3650', '3649']
```